# Scala Named Arguments

Tags: scala

I'm looking at this `Named Arguments` example in [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/):

```
scala> class Parent {
     | def foo(bar: Int = 1, baz: Int = 2): Int = bar + baz
     | }
defined class Parent

scala> class Child extends Parent {
     |    override def foo(baz: Int = 3, bar: Int = 4): Int = super.foo(baz, bar)
     | }
defined class Child

scala> val p = new Parent
p: Parent = Parent@6100756c

scala> p.foo()
res1: Int = 3

scala> val x = new Child
x: Child = Child@70605759
```

Calling `x.foo()` evaluates to 7 since `Child#foo` has default arguments of 3 and 4.

```
scala> x.foo()
res3: Int = 7
```

Instantiate a new `Child` at run-time, but `Parent` at compile-time. *This may or may not be correct*

```
scala> val y: Parent = new Child
y: Parent = Child@540b6fd1
```

Calling `x.foo()` evaluates to 7 since `Child#foo` has default arguments of 3 and 4.

```
scala> y.foo()
res5: Int = 7
```

Calling `x.foo()` evaluates to 4 since `Child#foo` has a default `baz` argument of 3.

```
scala> x.foo(bar = 1)
res6: Int = 4
```

However, I don't understand why `y.foo(bar = 1)` returns 5. I would've expected `Child#foo` to be evaluated since `y` is a `Child` type. Passing in a `bar` of 1 to `foo` means that `baz`'s default is 3. And so it should produce 4. But my understanding is of course incorrect.

```
scala> y.foo(bar = 1)
res7: Int = 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 reasons:

#### Default parameters implementation

`scala` compiler creates helper methods for default parameters:

```
val p = new Parent()
val c = new Child()

p.`foo$default$1`
// Int = 1
p.`foo$default$2`
// Int = 2

c.`foo$default$1`
// Int = 3
c.`foo$default$2`
// Int = 4
```

This is why you could use not only constants, but also fields and methods for default parameters:

```
def test(i: Int = util.Random.nextInt) = i

test()
// Int = -1102682999

test()
// Int = -1994652923
```

#### Named parameters implementation

There are no named parameters after compilation - all parameters are positional.

So since `bar` is second parameter of `Child#foo` this code:

```
c.foo(bar = 1)
// Int = 4
```

is translated by compiler to this:

```
c.foo(c.`foo$default$1`, /*bar = */1)
// Int = 4
```

But since `bar` is first parameter of `Parent#foo` this code:

```
val tmp: Parent = c
tmp.foo(bar = 1)
// Int = 5
```

is translated to this:

```
tmp.foo(/*bar = */1, tmp.`foo$default$2`)
// Int = 5
```

As we already know `c.foo$default$2` returns `4`, so `c.foo(1, 4)` returns 5.

Comment: so `tmp` uses `Parent`'s signature (positions of `bar and `baz`), but the default values of `Child`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith, actually `foo$default$2` is `Parent`'s method overridden by `Child`.